# Send email to multiple recipients with SKPSMTPMessage?

Tags: objective-c

I need to send email in background, so I have to use the library named: SMTP. And the main class I used is: SKPSMTPMessage. The problem is "ccEmail", when I add more than 2 recipients, it can't send email.  (that takes too long time to go to delegate methods). It works well with recipient <= 2.

```
smtpEmail.ccEmail = @"xyz@gmail.com, xyz1@gmail.com, xyz2@gmail.com";
```

Anyone knows this, please help me. Thanks you so much !

Comment: Anyone has solution for this, please help me. I have to use this way to send email : SMTP, but when I add many cc recipients, it does not work. I wonder why it's less than or equal 2 recipients only.

Comment: Hi, Is it work with 2 recipient? if so please let me know. i cant send email to more then 1 recipient using SKPSMTPMessage. Please reply

Answer (score 8):

There is my changes in the parseBuffer function:

```
case kSKPSMTPWaitingFromReply:
    {
        if ([tmpLine hasPrefix:@"250 "]) {

            if (!multipleRcptTo) {
                NSMutableString *multipleRcptToString = [NSMutableString string];
                [multipleRcptToString appendString:[self formatAddresses:toEmail]];
                [multipleRcptToString appendString:[self formatAddresses:ccEmail]];
                [multipleRcptToString appendString:[self formatAddresses:bccEmail]];

                multipleRcptTo = [[multipleRcptToString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r\n"] mutableCopy];
                [multipleRcptTo removeLastObject];
            } 
            if ([multipleRcptTo count] > 0) {
                NSString *rcptTo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [multipleRcptTo objectAtIndex:0]];
                [multipleRcptTo removeObjectAtIndex:0];

                //DEBUGLOG(@"C: %@", rcptTo);
                if (CFWriteStreamWriteFully((CFWriteStreamRef)outputStream, (const uint8_t *)[rcptTo UTF8String], [rcptTo lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]) < 0)
                {
                    error =  [outputStream streamError];
                    encounteredError = YES;
                }
                else
                {
                    [self startShortWatchdog];
                }
            } 
            if ([multipleRcptTo count] == 0) {
                sendState = kSKPSMTPWaitingToReply;

            }
        }
        break;
    }
```

and add this into header:

```
NSMutableArray *multipleRcptTo;
```

**EDIT** : Also change below method as `multipleRcptTo` is used as NSMutableString which is local declaration :

```
- (NSString *)formatAddresses:(NSString *)addresses {
  NSCharacterSet    *splitSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@";,"];
  NSMutableString   *multipleRcpt = [NSMutableString string];

  if ((addresses != nil) && (![addresses isEqualToString:@""])) {
    if( [addresses rangeOfString:@";"].location != NSNotFound || [addresses rangeOfString:@","].location != NSNotFound ) {
        NSArray *addressParts = [addresses componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:splitSet];

        for( NSString *address in addressParts ) {
            [multipleRcpt appendString:[self formatAnAddress:address]];
        }
    }
    else {
        [multipleRcpt appendString:[self formatAnAddress:addresses]];
    }       
  }

  return(multipleRcpt);
}
```

`SKPSMTPMessage` sends to the SMTP address all at once, and must send one by one.

Comment: It's a function in the SKPSMTPMessage class.