# Iphone to send email to multiple recipients using smtp server?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4

In my application i want to send email to multiple recipients.
i am able to send email to one person at a time and now i want to send email to multiple recipients.

i am having a nsmutable array *sNamesArr which content the data of the recipient.
 NSMutableArray *sNamesArr;

following is m code:

```
-(void)sendEMAIL
{
    NSLog(@"Paused state100");
    [dictUser retain];



    //Auto code


    SKPSMTPMessage *testMsg = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc] init];


    //testMsg.fromEmail = @"Lexi mobile";//nimit51parekh@gmail.com

    testMsg.fromEmail = str_uname;
    NSLog(@"str_Uname=%@",testMsg.fromEmail);

//    str_info = [str_info stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
//    testMsg.toEmail = str_info;
//    NSLog(@"autoemail=%@",testMsg.toEmail);

    //str_info = [str_info stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];

    testMsg.toEmail = str_info;
    NSLog(@"autoemail=%@",testMsg.toEmail);


    testMsg.relayHost = @"smtp.gmail.com";


    testMsg.requiresAuth = YES;


    testMsg.login = str_uname;
    NSLog(@"autoelogin=%@",testMsg.login);

    testMsg.pass = str_password;
    NSLog(@"autopass=%@",testMsg.pass);

    testMsg.subject = @"Schedule Sms And Email";


    testMsg.wantsSecure = YES; 



    NSString *sendmsg=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",str_info2];
    NSLog(@"automsg=%@",sendmsg);



    testMsg.delegate = self;


    NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/plain",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,



                               sendmsg,kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"8bit",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];





    testMsg.parts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:plainPart,nil];


    [testMsg send];

   // [self DeleteRowAfterSending];
    [self performSelector:@selector(DeleteRowAfterSending) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
}
```

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799112/send-email-to-multiple-recipients-with-skpsmtpmessage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the SKPSMTPMessage class is limited to sending to a single address at a time. So it seems that you have three choices:

1. Download the SKPSMTPMessage code and modify it to support a list of TO addresses.
2. Write your own SMTP client library to send to multiple recipients. If you know that your messages will not contain attachments and have predictable content then the task of writing an SMTP socket client will be easier.
3. If your app is already talking to services that you control, add a service end-point to send the emails where the phone sends the content and recipients and the service does all of the SMTP work.

Answer (score 2):

SKPSMTPMessage sends to the SMTP address all at once, and must send one by one.

This link would be really helpful for you.

[Send email to multiple recipients with SKPSMTPMessage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799112/send-email-to-multiple-recipients-with-skpsmtpmessage)